# network routing paths for different tcp channels but for same machines

Tags: language-agnostic, networking, routes, tcp, network-programming

Process1 runs in machineA. Process1 has opened server portX.
Process2 runs in machineB. Process2 has opened server portY.
Process1 & Process2 exchange messages over 2 different tcp channels.

```
Process1 opens client socket to portY of machineB and start sending msgs to Process2.  (tcp channel 1)
Process2 opens client socket to portX of machineA and start sending msgs to Process1.  (tcp channel 2)
```

**Question:**
Is the network path the same for channel1 & channel2 in all cases? I.e. go through same routers etc?
**UPDATE:**
I need this information to make some decision concerning synchronization of processes (so that 1 process is not faster than the other

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this: If the path between two system is always the same ... why should someone cared about designing [routing protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_protocol).

Comment: why would you expect that the routing algorithm of the routing protocol, in the specific example I am asking, would return different routes for each traversal side?

Comment: @user384706 Because that's up to the routing algorithm to assign a path to each session. You may decide (just as an example) to assign your next hop in a round robin fashion selected from the list of possible routers (with a route to dest available). Or you may change next hop priorities depending on path load. That's the point on designing a layered protocol: upper layers don't need to bother on low level details. The cost to pay is nevertheles great: you can't design a real time protocol on these premises.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee about it. Is this related to your other question about interleaving?

Comment: And in the real world, asymmetric paths are sometimes seen.

Comment: Yes.It seems that I could not express the other question in a manner that was clear to others